# I want to call APNS device token in my library files

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, static-libraries

I am creating the library file(.a file) which will store the device token on the server, but as per my knowledge(i am very much naive in native ios) AppDelegate is not available in the library files and device token can only be received in the app delegate.Is there any other method to do the same. Any suggestion or help will be highly obliged.

Comment: Completely wrong: you can get the delegate from `UIApplication` singleton at the library code, token can be received and stored by any class, but what you want to do is to let user decide how to receive the token and then use your public API to process it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible.

The standard approach is you create one method to save device token and make it available for users so they can call your library method to save device token manually.